# SQL Select to make a value appear only once

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

For those that have been helping me along the way with this twitter-clone, thank you!!  With your help, I've managed to get most things working and finally now to the last steps of the followers function.

Right now, I have a dataset with the following fields: username, tweet, date

An example of the data could look like:

```
Username    Tweet             Date
kenny       hi!               2011-10-07 19:07:00
stan        hello             2011-10-05 18:07:00
kenny       looks like rain   2011-10-05 17:07:00
stan        hello             2011-10-05 14:07:00
cartman     authoritay!       2010-10-05 14:07:00
```

And I've been wrestling with the SQL statement that would produce a data set in which each user appears only once with their latest tweet.  So, based on the above, something that looks like this:

```
Username    Tweet             Date
kenny       hi!               2011-10-07 19:07:00
stan        hello             2011-10-05 18:07:00
cartman     authoritay!       2010-10-05 14:07:00
```

I've been googling sql searches and have tried variations of COUNT, DISTINCT, MAX, but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Are you using MySql or MS SQL database?

Comment: Try using distinct expression, what's the SQL script statement your using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using a mysql database

Comment: I tried a ton of statements over the course of the day, unfortunately.  I tried DISTINCT again just now on the username, but it didn't produce any effect.  I actually simplified my dataset for the purpose of posting this question, but my actual statement was something like this:

SELECT DISTINCT username, content, `date` from tweets WHERE
user_id IN (SELECT users.id FROM users
INNER JOIN user_users ON users.id = user_users.followed_user_id
WHERE user_users.user_id = 1)
ORDER BY date desc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select d1.username, d1.tweet, d1.date from data d1 where d1.date = 
    (select max(d2.date) from data d2 where d1.username = d2.username)
```

Comment: thank you!  I don't understand this syntax, but let me study it.

Answer (score 9):

Would it not work just by

```
select distinct username, tweet, date order by date desc
```

(This is MSSQL syntax)

With new data in hand:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tweets.username, content, date from tweets 
WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT users.id FROM users 
  INNER JOIN user_users ON users.id = user_users.followed_user_id 
WHERE user_users.user_id = 1) 
ORDER BY date desc
```

Comment: Actually, that was almost the exact statement I tried (I think).  My actual dataset is a bit more complicated as I'm pulling the data from other tables.  I tried this, but it didnt make each username appear only once:  SELECT DISTINCT username, content, `date` from tweets WHERE
user_id IN (SELECT users.id FROM users
INNER JOIN user_users ON users.id = user_users.followed_user_id
WHERE user_users.user_id = 1)
ORDER BY date desc

Comment: Or maybe not... What columns do you actually have in your tweets table?

Comment: Hi, thanks, but actually, I just tried explicitly putting the tweets.username , but still no luck.  :(

Comment: Actually, I realized I'm not supposed to have a username within my tweets table.  So now my tweets table looks like this:

tweets (id, user_id, content)

I just tried DISTINCT tweets.user_id, but the resulting set still included duplicate (or more) user_ids

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f.*
FROM (
      SELECT Username, MAX(`Date`) as maxval
      FROM  table GROUP BY Username    
     ) AS x INNER JOIN table AS f
ON f.Username  = x.Username  AND f.`Date`= x.maxval
```