# SQL Duplicate value1 Max value2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am quite new to SQL and my question is very similar to the problem posted in here. However, my Username and Date are in two different databases. Also, I'd like for the output Date to be the maximum it could be.

[SQL Select to make a value appear only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686049/sql-select-to-make-a-value-appear-only-once)

```
SELECT
PART.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,

CAST(CASE WHEN WO.PARTS_PER_PANEL * WOM.[QUAN_BOM] = 0 THEN NULL --casts to INT & in case, checks off divide by 0
ELSE WO.QUAN_SCH / NULLIF(WO.PARTS_PER_PANEL * WOM.[QUAN_BOM],0)
END AS INT) AS TotalRequired,

Convert(INT,IPA.[CONSIGN_ONHAND_QTY] + IPA.[QUAN_ON_HAND] + IPA.[QUAN_ON_ORDER] - (WO.QUAN_SCH / NULLIF(WO.PARTS_PER_PANEL,0) * WOM.[QUAN_BOM])) AS [Difference]

FROM
…
WHERE
  PART.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER LIKE '%512255%'
```

[image]

The Output should be something like this. Instead there are 4 outputs.

```
CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER....TotalRequired...OnHand
1212255   …              MAX() …    MAX()
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results in *this* question.

Comment: Hi! A question, do you mean "tables" when you state that your fields "are in two different databases" - or do you actually mean databases? Please post the SQL that you are working with. And please complete the question with an example set of the data that you are working with. Linking to another question is not really good practice, I would advice that you flesh out you question completly to stand independent of any other.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: would it be helpful to submit the code I am working with?

Comment: @AndreasLorenzen I mean two different tables. There are multiple tables being linked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inner query for this - since you already have your result, but just in multiple rows. So an easy solution would be this:

```sql
SELECT
  inner_result.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
  ... (your other fields)
  MAX(inner_result.TotalRequired) as [TotalRequired],
  ... (your other fields wrapped with MAX())
  MAX(inner_result.Difference) as [Difference]
FROM (
  SELECT
    PART.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
    CAST(CASE
      WHEN WO.PARTS_PER_PANEL * WOM.[QUAN_BOM] = 0 THEN NULL --casts to INT & in case,
      ELSE WO.QUAN_SCH / NULLIF(WO.PARTS_PER_PANEL * WOM.[QUAN_BOM],0)
    END AS INT) AS TotalRequired,
    CONVERT(INT,
      IPA.[CONSIGN_ONHAND_QTY] +
      IPA.[QUAN_ON_HAND] +
      IPA.[QUAN_ON_ORDER] -
      (WO.QUAN_SCH / NULLIF(WO.PARTS_PER_PANEL,0) * WOM.[QUAN_BOM])
    ) AS [Difference]
  FROM ...
  WHERE
    PART.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER LIKE '%512255%') as inner_result
GROUP BY
  inner_result.CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
  ... (your other fields that are not involved in a MAX() function)
```

If you have trouble using this solution, then supply the entire query - and I can edit it for you.

Comment: I found out that maxing those values, and turning my one of my string outputs to an integer then MAXing it worked. This got me half way. Thanks!